# Form submission handler is not executed

Tags: 7, forms

In a module, I am using the following code.

```
function mysimple_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#method'] = 'get';
  $form['#action'] = '/buy/{_val_}';
  $form['search_location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Search',
    '#default_value' => t('kathmandu'),
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array(
      'placeholder' => t('Search')
    )
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'mysimple_form_submit';
  return $form;
}

function mysimple_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  krumo('asdsads');
  die();
}
```

I am using that form in `hook_node_view()`.

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('mysimple_form');
  $node->content['simpleform'] = array(
    '#weight' => -1,
    '#markup'=> drupal_render($form)
  );
}
```

The form is displayed perfectly, but the callback function doesn't seem to work.
I also tried `$form['actions']['#submit][] = 'mysimple_form_submit';` and  `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit][] = 'mysimple_form_submit';` but the form submission handler is still not invoked.

Comment: And without `die();`?

Comment: @leymannx Doesn't change anything, still doesn't call.

Answer (score 1):

There is two problems:

1. You form method is **GET** so form submit action will be the actual path with the params like `node/10?search_location=kathmandu&op=Search&form_build_id=form-s4JrAE91au_BWakeBLD7RUsktRTBXFCpJQrnHGiOjg8&form_token=ES2W0RDpLOnWZUsXOnP4f9gBmSXcYLvqhO9uy1ee4Vk&form_id=d7_exp_form`
2. The second one you set your action to `'/buy/{_val_}'` so automatically after the submit you will redirect to `/buy/{_val_}` without invoke the submit handler.

**Suggestion:**

1. If you want to invoke the submit handler remove the `$form['#method']` and `$form['#action']`, so your form will be with post method and your submit handler will invoked.
2. Remove only `$form['#method']` and create menu entry `/buy/%` and you can do your submit handler logic in the `/buy/%` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't need to specify custom submit handler because if your form ID is `mysimple_form`, Drupal should use `mysimple_form_submit` as default form submission function.

For more info see the https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#submit_property

Comment: Thank you your suggestion was the first thing I tried and also a variations of it. No luck so far.